# Write a text file in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I cannot find any mention of writing strings to a text file in Codename One. I need to create and maintain a "directory" of saved image groups so I can retrieve the name of the group and then retrieve the images by their saved name in ImageViewer. Has anyone developed an imitation of the Java FileWriter?

Answer (score 1):

Codename One has a `Writer` class but not a `FileWriter` since the file system is a bit different from the one on the OS.

You can just use `FileSystemStorage` or `Storage` to write a text file just like you can in Java SE using `OutputStream` or `Writer`. E.g.:

```
FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
String fileName = fs.getAppHomePath() + "my_file.txt";
try(Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(fs.openInputStream(fileName))) {
    w.write("This is the text in the file");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I will work with my list by using InputStream to read the file into a list object, adding the new line to the list, then rewriting the list back to the file.